# (Etch-a-Sketch) Why only the rows and not the columns are generated?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was working on my Etch-a-Sketch project and there is an issue with `populateBoard()` function, it seems only the rows are generated, why?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <title>Sketchpad</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" a href="reset.css"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" a href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="flex-conainer">
        <div class="title"><h1>Sketchpad</h1></div>
        <div class="content">
        <div class="board"></div>
        <div class="buttons">
            <button>Black</button>
            <button>White</button>
            <button>Random</button>
            <button>Reset</button>
        </div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Size of Board" value="16" onchange="changeSize(this.value)"/>
        
        <button>Set size:</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="Main.js"></script>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
function populateBoard(size) {
    let board = document.querySelector('.board');

    board.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${size}, 1fr;)`;
    board.style.gridTemplateRows = `repeat(${size}, 1fr)`;

    for (let i =0 ; i<256; i++) {
        let square = document.createElement('div');
        square.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
        board.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', square);
    };
}

function changeSize(input) {
    populateBoard(input);
};
```

CSS:

```
.board {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    display: grid;
}
```

Overall I want my grid to be interactive and to be able o change once I input a size.

Comment: Can you try to correc this line:  `repeat(${size}, 1fr;)`; (see ; there)?

Comment: what do you mean by correcting it?